# How to refactor complex search logic in a Rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, refactoring, dry

My search method is smelly and bloated, and I need some help refactoring it. I'm new to Ruby, and I haven't figured out how to leverage it effectively, which leads to bloated methods like this:

```
  # discussion.rb
  def self.search(params)
    # If there is a search query, use Tire gem for fulltext search
    if params[:query].present?
      tire.search(load: true) do
        query { string params[:query] }
      end

    # Otherwise grab all discussions based on category and/or filter
    else

      # Grab all discussions and include the author
      discussions = self.includes(:author)

      # Filter by category if there is one specified
      discussions = discussions.where(category: params[:category]) if params[:category]

      # If params[:filter] is provided, user it
      if params[:filter]
        case params[:filter]
        when 'hot'
          discussions = discussions.open.order_by_hot
        when 'new'
          discussions = discussions.open.order_by_new
        when 'top'
          discussions = discussions.open.order_by_top
        else
          # If params[:filter] does not match the above three states, it's probably a status
          discussions = discussions.order_by_new.where(status: params[:filter])
        end
      else

        # If no filter is passed, just grab discussions by hot
        discussions = discussions.open.order_by_hot
      end
    end
  end

  STATUSES   = {
    question:   %w[answered],
    suggestion: %w[started completed declined],
    problem:    %w[solved]
  }

  scope :order_by_hot,  order('...') DESC, created_at DESC")
  scope :order_by_new,  order('created_at DESC')
  scope :order_by_top,  order('votes_count DESC, created_at DESC')
```

This is a Discussion model that can be filtered (or not) by a category: `question`, `problem`, `suggestion`.

All discussions or a single category can be filtered further by `hot`, `new`, `votes`, or `status`. Status is a hash in the model and it has several values depending on the category (status filter only appears if params[:category] is present).

Complicating matters is a fulltext search feature using Tire

But my controller looks nice and tidy:

```
  def index
    @discussions = Discussion.search(params)
  end
```

Can I dry this up/refactor it a little, maybe using meta programming or blocks? I managed to extract this out of the controller, but then ran out of ideas. I don't know Ruby well enough to take this further.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For starters, "Grab all discussions based on category and/or filter" can be a separate method.

`params[:filter]` is repeated many times, so take that out at the top:

```
filter = params[:filter]
```

You can use

```
if [:hot, :new, :top].incude? filter
  discussions = discussions.open.send "order_by_#{filter}"
...
```

Also, factor out if then else if case else statements. I prefer break into separate methods and return early:

```
def do_something
  return 'foo' if ...
  return 'bar' if ...
  'baz'
end
```

`discussions = discussions...` appears many times, but looks weird. Can you use `return discussions...` instead?

Why does the constant `STATUSES` appear at the end? Usually constants appear at the top of the model.

Be sure to write all your tests before refactoring.

To respond to the comment about `return 'foo' if ...`:

Consider:

```
def evaluate_something
  if a==1
    return 'foo'
  elsif b==2
    return 'bar'
  else
    return 'baz'
  end
end
```

I suggest refactoring this to:

```
def evaluate_something
  return 'foo' if a==1
  return 'bar' if b==2
  'baz'
end
```

Perhaps you can refactor some of your if..then..else..if statements.

Recommended book: [Clean Code](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132350882)

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. I ended up with this: http://pastie.org/5166966 -- As for the constants, they are at the top; I just pasted them at the bottom for clarity.

Comment: PS: Not sure what you meant by `return 'foot' if`, though. And the duplicate `discussions = discussions`, I took that out, but I have to leave it for `where` clauses, otherwise nothing comes back.